# Trying to put borders in consecutive <div> in php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to put borders in my code with "float: left" to try to obtain this solution:

[image: 1]

But when I put in the CSS the "border" style, I obtain this:

[image: 2]

My code and solution:

**php code:**

```
<?php

function pinta($n,$m){
    $cadena="";
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){

            $x = 0+$i*10;
            $y = 0+$j*10;
            $cadena.="<div style='background-color:rgb(0,$x,$y); '>&nbsp;</div>";
        }
        $cadena.="<br/>";
    }
    return $cadena;
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- start static html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>cursor</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            echo pinta(9,9);
        ?>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css code:**

```
div{
    width:40px;
    float: left;
}
```

[image: 3]

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible, I've got this: https://imgur.com/a/KuI7IV4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
div{
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/NWaErej)